# How to find out the credentials of a gvfs share mount

Tags: mount, samba, cifs, gvfs

Until recently I opened a share on my local network by typing into the filebrowser (PCmanFM)

```
smb://192.168.0.105/BEN
```

This was easy and I did not need any password or user credentials to do it.

Now I need to mount this share via `cifs`. But how are the credentials? How did `gvfs` connect to the share without me giving any of the credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

Upon connection via the file browser, `cvfs` automatically uses the share's user, share and password.

If you are in a similar position, open up the connection in the file browser and then pick "open directory in terminal". Now the terminal will show the directory in the gvfs-way, meaning it will display the share name like this:

```
ben@ZOTAC:/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.100.175,share=hap_internal/lost+found$
```

The share name is "hap_internal".

To find out about the users that are able to login to a certain share you can use `nbtscan`, which is in the repositories, which scans local shares and displays their potential users..

```
ben@ZOTAC:~$ nbtscan 192.168.100.0/24
Doing NBT name scan for addresses from 192.168.100.0/24

IP address       NetBIOS Name     Server    User             MAC address      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
192.168.100.0   Sendto failed: Permission denied
192.168.100.102  OMV              <server>  OMV              00:00:00:00:00:00
192.168.100.159  ZOTAC            <server>  ZOTAC            00:00:00:00:00:00
192.168.100.255 Sendto failed: Permission denied
192.168.100.175  HAP-S1           <server>  HAP-S1           00:00:00:00:00:00
ben@ZOTAC:~$
```

The share user to login to the share name is "HAP-S1".

All this information was used by gvfs behind the curtains to establish the connection.

The password would be impossible to find out, but since the filebrowser was able to connect to the share via gvfs I figured it would be blank.

You can now use those credentials in a `cifs` mount:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o nounix,uid=LOCALUSR,user=SHAREUSR,password=SHAREPWD //192.168.0.102/SHARENAME/ /media/mountpoint
```